# Draw line in ComboBox in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, graphics, line

How can I create line in comboBoxItem programmatically in Silverlight?
I would like to get something like this:
[image]

Thanks.

I tried to do like:

```
 var lineTypeComboBox = new ComboBox
        {
            Width = 40,
            Background = Background,
            Margin = new Thickness(0),
            Padding = new Thickness(0)
        };
        lineTypeComboBox.Items.Add(new Line {X1 = 1, X2 = 20, Y1 = 1, Y2 = 20});
```

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: @icebat , I tried to just add a line like comboboxitem or add a line in stackpanel - nothing helps.

Comment: I don't really see how that could not work. Please add your code, that will help us to find the issue.

Comment: @icebat , I added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see from your code that you didn't set Line's `Stroke` color. Try setting it to black (and don't forget to add ComboBox to some container):

```
var lineTypeComboBox = new ComboBox
         {
            Width = 40,
            Background = Background,
            Margin = new Thickness(0),
            Padding = new Thickness(0)
         };
lineTypeComboBox.Items.Add(new Line { X1 = 1, X2 = 20, Y1 = 1, Y2 = 20, Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) });
//add ComboBox to StackPanel
spMain.Children.Add(lineTypeComboBox);
```

Also I don't really think that' a good approach to write all this in code like in Win Forms. Why not XAML, one of the best parts of Silverlight? Oh, and your line coordinates are a bit off, you draw it diagonally.
How about this?

```
<ComboBox Width="40">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Line">
            <Setter Property="X1" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Y1" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="X2" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Y2" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <Line StrokeThickness="1" />            
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <Line StrokeThickness="3" />            
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <Line StrokeThickness="5" />            
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

You can set all the properties directly instead of the Style, but that will be less flexible.